# Obtaining reward from console games for Reinforcement Learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to use reinforcement learning (RL) such as Q-learning or A3C for console games. I don't have the source code for any of these games so creating an environment might not be possible. For RL the network needs a reward for it's action; my issue is how to get that reward. For example, in Halo, killing someone should be a positive reward (+1) and dying negative (-1). There is no indicator on the screen when you score a kill or when you die. If needed, I am using Python and Tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet could be using audio cues. I know for a fact that the Halo announcer makes a specific sound when the player dies or gets a kill.

If tensor flow has some way to grab audio and recognize it compared to a given sample this could be a valid method for checking if the player has gotten a kill or died.

*Disclaimer: I've not used TensorFlow before.*

Comment: Down-voter can you please explain your displeasure with my answer?

Comment: I didn't Down-voter you comment, someone else did. Your answer is helpful